# How to stop multi-word links being placed together on a new line, instead splitting them up like regular text?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, whitespace

I have a site powered by Wordpress, and on one of my posts I have the following text.

Any readers interested in the different ways to interpret utils are encouraged to read about the difference between [Ordinal and Cardinal Utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility#Cardinal).

If Wordpress can't put all of the text "Ordinal and Cardinal Utility" on the same line as "between" it puts it all on a completely new line, which can look really clunky, especially on mobile. Because it's a hyperlink it's prioritising keeping it as one item whereas I'm happy for the words to be split over multiple lines, just as it would if it wasn't a hyperlink. I know this is a basic problem but for some reason I haven't found any solutions online. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS property you're looking for is either [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) or [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), depending on the look/style/effect that you're going for. By default, the [`<a> anchor element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) is an `inline` display, which allows the text to wrap.

Here are a few examples:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  background: #e4e6e9;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

a {
  background: #0094ee;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ib {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ws-nw {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  Usually, <a href="#">links are "inline" which means they wrap around once they hit</a> the side of the container.
</div>

<div id="b">
  You can have them <a href="#" class="ib"> set to inline-block to prevent broken wrapping</a>, but the text still wraps. inside the block
</div>

<div id="c">
  You can avoid <a href="#" class="ws-nw">any wrapping at all by setting</a> it to white-space: nowrap;. Be careful on <a href="#" class="ws-nw">super long text though because it can cause unexpected results on small containers</a>.
</div>
```